# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : coercizione di classe ‘"by"’ in data.frame non possibile

Tags: r, survival

I am working on a dataset of patients treated with 2 different treatments.
The treatments are coded as "1" and "2" in the "T" column.
I am evaluating the effect of the different treatments in age subgroups, thus I categorized the "age" variable in "0" and "1" according to the median.

I wrote this:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)

sub_age0 <- my_data[my_data$age_category==0, ]
sub_age1 <- my_data[my_data$age_category==1, ]
sub_age0 <- as.data.frame(sub_age0)
sub_age1 <- as.data.frame(sub_age1)


fit_age1 <- survfit(Surv(mesi.OS, OS.status) ~ T, data = sub_age0)
med_os_age1 <- surv_median(fit_age1)
age_plot1 <- ggsurvplot(fit_age1,
                       title = "Overall Survival",
                       xscale = "d_m",
                       break.time.by = 365.25,
                       pval = TRUE,
                       pval.method = TRUE,
                       risk.table = TRUE,
                       risk.table.col = "strata",
                       risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE,
                       surv.median.line = "hv",
                       median.line.text = paste0("Median OS = ", med_os_age1$mesi.OS),
                       legend.title = "Age",
                       legend.labs = c("Pembro", "Pembro-CT"),
                       palette = q1)
```

But I received this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: Hi Ludovica! Welcome to StackOverflow.  1. Which line do you get the error on? 2. While I think your question could potentially be solved without a sample dataframe, a sample dataframe wouldn't hurt (and would certainly mean it would attract more answers) - you can use dput(head()) on your inputs and add them to your question